# Using @PropertySouce in @Component

Tags: spring

I tried to use `@PropertySource` in a `@Component` like:

```
@Component
@PropertySource("somepropertiesfile.properties")
public class Student {
    ...
}
```

It worked fine.

I want to understand, what is the different between using `@PropertySource` with `@Component` and `@PropertySource` with `@Configuration`.

Is there any difference or impact of using `@PropertySource` with `@Component`.

Answer (score 2):

`Configuration` is itself a `Component` type, look into the @Configuration annotation implementation below.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Configuration {

}
```

**From API**

*Component*: Indicates that an annotated class is a "component". Such classes are considered as candidates for auto-detection when using annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning.

*Configuration*: Indicates that a class declares one or more @Bean methods and may be processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and service requests for those beans at runtime.

The @Bean annotation is used to indicate that a method instantiates, configures and initializes a new object to be managed by the Spring IoC container. These are same as Spring’s  XML configuration. `You can use @Bean annotated methods with any Spring @Component, however, they are most often used with @Configuration beans`.

Here also you can use @PropertySource in @Component class but these are most suitable for @Configuration classes as it is a configuration related task.

You can refer [Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts) for detailed information.

Comment: I read about "You can use Bean annotated methods with any Spring Component, however, they are most often used with Configuration beans." in the doc. but it is not mentioned anywhere that we can use PropertySource with @Component or not

Comment: PropertySource is type of configuration task and its better place is @Configuration class. For example we can define `@Bean` annotated method inside Component class also but we prefer Configuration class as this is separate annotation designation available for it. I agree document doesn't specify this case but we can correlate this case with @Bean definition case. Not sure spring may restrict later to specify all configurations inside @Configuration class, so it is always good to follow most appropriate path.